# How to delete row=2 in excel using python openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

How do I delete Row 2 ?

I have tried this code, but does not work  :

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("input1.xlsx")
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet")

for i1 in range(1, sheet.max_row):
    if sheet_old1.cell(i1, 1).value is None:
        sheet_old1.delete_rows(2, amount=1)
        
wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Kindly indent your code and let us know whats wrong with the code you have posted.

Comment: using above code not able to delete row number 2

Comment: So what happens instead? Why specifically mention "row number 2" -- did you test it with 'row number 1', 'row number 3' etc., and with these it *does* work?

Comment: sheet.delete_rows(2, amount=1) This is deleting starting 3 rows instead of row=2

Comment: this might help you https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line as this is for **deleting multiple rows**.

```
sheet_old1.delete_rows(2, amount=1)
```

to, [this is for **single row deletion**]

```
sheet_old1.delete_rows(2)
```

sample link http://thequickblog.com/openpyxl-insertion-and-deletion-of-rows-and-columns/